# How do I configure WordPress so that it doesn't make calls to `wp-ajax` now that I'm no longer using a side cart plugin?

Tags: wordpress, javascript, css, ajax, woocommerce

I was using  [WooCommerce side cart plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/side-cart-woocommerce/) on my website. I noticed that the plugin caused heavy process on my web site, so I decided to remove the plugin.

I tested my website with gtmetrix.

[image]

For the row `post ?wp-ajax=...`:

- by reactivating the plugin the row will be doubled
- by removing or disabling the plugin one row up to over 5 seconds remaining

maybe this is not related to that plugin at all?

How do I configure WordPress to not make that AJAX call at all?

I have replaced another plugin instead of side cart plugin.

I found this on other website, smaller codes without that ajax row on gtmetrix:

`{"fragments":{"div.widget_shopping_cart_content":"<div class=\"widget_shopping_cart_content\">\n<div class=\"shopping-cart-widget-body woodmart-scroll\">\n\t<div class=\"woodmart-scroll-content\">\n\n\t\t\n\t\t\t<p class=\"woocommerce-mini-cart__empty-message empty\">\u0633\u0628\u062f \u062e\u0631\u06cc\u062f \u0634\u0645\u0627 \u062e\u0627\u0644\u06cc \u0627\u0633\u062a.<\/p>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<p class=\"return-to-shop\">\n\t\t\t\t\t<a class=\"button wc-backward\" href=\"https:\/\/www.reliefshop.ir\/products\/\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\u0628\u0627\u0632\u06af\u0634\u062a \u0628\u0647 \u0641\u0631\u0648\u0634\u06af\u0627\u0647\t\t\t\t\t<\/a>\n\t\t\t\t<\/p>\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\n\t<\/div>\n<\/div>\n\n<div class=\"shopping-cart-widget-footer woodmart-cart-empty\">\n\t\n\t<\/div>\n<\/div>","span.woodmart-cart-number":"\t\t\t<span class=\"woodmart-cart-number\">0 <span>\u0622\u06cc\u062a\u0645<\/span><\/span>\n\t\t","span.woodmart-cart-subtotal":"\t\t\t<span class=\"woodmart-cart-subtotal\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\">0&nbsp;<span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">\u062a\u0648\u0645\u0627\u0646<\/span><\/span><\/span>\n\t\t"},"cart_hash":""}`

Comment: See on [wordpress.se]: [Stop admin-ajax?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/296836/stop-admin-ajax)